# SOAP XML parser 0 rows/ NULL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to parse `Message` out of the following xml. Despite the numerous similar answers, nothing seems to work.

```
declare @x xml

select @x=N'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <SubmitDocumentsResponse xmlns="http://somesite/webservices/">
      <SubmitDocumentsResult>
        <Code>000</Code>
        <Message>Success.</Message>
        <ItemsCreated>
          <ServiceItemCreated>
            <Id>2816</Id>
            <Protocol>ΑΚ - ΠΠ6</Protocol>
            <SubmitDate>28/03/2022 16:05</SubmitDate>
          </ServiceItemCreated>
        </ItemsCreated>
      </SubmitDocumentsResult>
    </SubmitDocumentsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
select @x

select r.value('Message[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Parsed Result]
from @x.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:SubmitDocumentsResponse/*:SubmitDocumentsResult') as t(r)
```

This returns one row with NULL value.
Other things I've tried:

```
r.value('Message[1]','nvarchar(max)') -- same error
r.value('(Message)[1]','nvarchar(max)') -- same error
r.value('(@Message)[1]','nvarchar(max)') -- same error
r.value('Message','nvarchar(max)') -- error,requires a singleton
@x.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/SubmitDocumentsResponse/SubmitDocumentsResult') -- yields 0 rows
@x.nodes('//SubmitDocumentsResult') -- yields 0 rows
```

This also yields 0 rows:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap)
select r.value('Message[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Parsed Result]
from @x.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*SubmitDocumentsResponse/*:SubmitDocumentsResult') as t(r)
```

How do I parse the attribute? What am I missing?

Comment: And yet you were very close: in your first query, write `*:Message` instead of `Message` and there you go. Remember that all children of `SubmitDocumentsResponse` are also in the namespace `http://somesite/webservices/`. A more elegant approach is `with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://somesite/webservices/', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as soap) select ...` and then use `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SubmitDocumentsResponse/SubmitDocumentsResult` rather than wildcards.

Comment: It works! Well, at least I proved I tried. You can make this into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap,
                    'http://somesite/webservices/' as ns2)
select 
   r.value('ns2:Code[1]','char(3)') as [Code],
   r.value('ns2:Message[1]','nvarchar(20)') as [Parsed Result],
   r.value('ns2:ItemsCreated[1]/ns2:ServiceItemCreated[1]/ns2:Id[1]','int') as Id
from @x.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:SubmitDocumentsResponse/ns2:SubmitDocumentsResult') as t(r)
```

output:

| Code | Parsed Result | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | Success. | 2816 |

Docs:

- [WITH NAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `/text()` is slightly faster, also you can use just one `[1]` if you put the whole thing in brackets, and you can make `ns2` a `DEFAULT` namespace, so `(ItemsCreated/ServiceItemCreated/Id/text())[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using namespaces, you need to add these in to the XQuery. the easiest way to do this is with a `XMLNAMESPACES` block. Using `*` is very slow.

You can even make one of the namespaces the default:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap,
    DEFAULT 'http://somesite/webservices/'
)
select 
   r.value('(Code/text())[1]','char(3)') as [Code],
   r.value('(Message/text())[1]','nvarchar(20)') as [Parsed Result],
   r.value('(ItemsCreated/ServiceItemCreated/Id/text())[1]','int') as Id
from @x.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SubmitDocumentsResponse/SubmitDocumentsResult') as t(r)
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e02c7f1e7324ac46c00e68a7164ffba)

Note that using `text()` to get the inner text of a node is slightly faster.